# How to access an image from firebase storage?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, quasar-framework

I want to access an image I've uploaded to the firebase storage. I've tried what they tell me in https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files but it just doesn't work.

What I want to do is pretty simple. I have a "img" tag with a source. 
Using Vue.js, I want to assign the uploaded file path to the image source.

This is what I have now:

```
loadImage(details) {
  console.log(details.email);
  var storage = firebaseApp.storage();
  var gsReference = storage.refFromURL('gs://icachatdam.appspot.com/profilePics/jordi@test.com/profPic.png')
  this.picture = gsReference.fullPath;
}
```

where the variable "picture" is the image source:

```
<q-img :src="this.picture" spinner-color="white" style="height: 140px; max-width: 150px" />
```

Comment: You can't use a gs:// URL to load an image into the browser.  You have to get a download URL as described in the documentation. https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to Doug's reply I've been testing a bit more and this has finally worked for me:

```
loadImage(details) {
  var starsRef = firebaseApp.storage().ref().child('profilePics/'+details.email+'/profPic.png');

  starsRef
    .getDownloadURL()
    .then(url => {
      this.pictureURL = url;
      //console.log(this.pictureURL);
    });
}
```